# Tibco SQLException

Tags: tibco

I am encountering this error again and again in my tibco code.Somebody please tell how to solve this error
I am using tibco 5.7.3.

JDBC error reported: (SQLState = HY000) - java.sql.SQLException: [tibcosoftwareinc][SQLServer JDBC Driver]Object has been closed."

Answer (score 5):

When a JDBC Query activity is configured to query in subset mode, the resultSet object is kept in the engine for subsequent iterations. Typically the resultSet object will only be closed and cleared from the engine if there is no more data left. However, keep in mind that the default connection `idleTimeout` is set to 5 minutes.  This means that after 5 minutes of no activity the connection will get released.  So if you wait longer than the `idleTimeout` value to retrieve subsequent subsets you will incur this exception since the connection has been closed and hence the resultset is no longer available.

**Resolution:**
Set `Engine.DBConnection.idleTimeout` to higher value in the Businessworks engine TRA file, say, 20 minutes so this connection can remain idle without getting released for next iterations for example: `Engine.DBConnection.idleTimeout=20`.  For more details on this setting please see the list of [Available Custom Engine Properties](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/activematrix_businessworks/5.7.2_september_2009/bw/html/tib_bw_administration/admin.5.69.htm).

Comment: Hi i have tried increasing java.property.bw.engine.dbConnection.idleTimeout value to higher value and redeployed my project again but it still throws the same error.I just wanted to know whether connecting via VPN and running the process makes any difference.

Comment: I have modified my answer to reflect the documented property name.  Can you please apply that property to your .tra file?